# BottomNavigationView hidden by default after adding scroll behaviour

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx

I have the following main layout and a recyclerview in my fragment. The problem i am facing is that the bottom navigation view is hidden by default and appears only when i scroll down the navigation view appears.

Before scrolling down
[image: before scrolling down]
After scrolling down the bottomnavigationview appears
[image: after scrolling down]

Another issue i am facing is that after scrolling down and changing the fragment the toolbar disappears

content_home.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".activity.HomeActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_foreground"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_foreground"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />



    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/navigation" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the main activity layout
activity_home.xml

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_home" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in your `content_home.xml`You are using `app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"` in `BottomNavigationView`.

**That's why it is happing.**

**Remove** `hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior`from `app:layout_behavior`.

Comment: i removed it still it remains hidden

Comment: He used `app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"` to show/hide bottom navigation bar on scroll.

Comment: fixed it up by removing content_home.xml and putting all the content in a coordinator layout also replaced the hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior with custom behaviour